# Meaning of "to fail at one's peril" in a legal document from the Elizabethan period

Tags: meaning, phrases, legalese

I do not know what "to fail at one's peril" means. The phrase appears in legal documents until the 19th century (at least this is what Google suggests). I cannot deduce its meaning no matter how hard I try.

Comment: General reference: Googling **define "at one's peril"** shows a clear definition *with risk or danger to one; at the hazard of* on the first reference, without even leaving Google homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The complete sentence is often something like, "Whereof you may not fail, at your peril." This means that if you fail, it will be perilous for you.